# How to get value of custom EF6 Designer property

Tags: entity-framework-6, t4

I have succesfully extended the EF6 designer to allow for some custom properties on my entities, associations and properties using this post:

[Extending Entity Framework 6 - adding custom properties to entities in designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25446746/extending-entity-framework-6-adding-custom-properties-to-entities-in-designer)

Now I need to use these custom properties when generating code in T4 but I have no clue how to access that information. Can someone point me in the right direction ?

regards,
Jurjen.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out.

looking at, for instance, the entity variable in "foreach (var entity in typeMapper.GetItemsToGenerate(itemCollection))", this is a GlobalItem (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.globalitem(v=vs.110).aspx) wich contains MetadataProperties.

Listing these properties using a simple foreach

```
foreach( var mp in entity.MetadataProperties)
{ 
    this.WriteLine("{0} = '{1}'", mp.Name, mp.Value);
}
```

results in a list

```
Name = 'Role'
NamespaceName = 'Model1'
Abstract = 'False'
...
http://saop.si:RecordTracked = '<a:RecordTracked xmlns:a="http://saop.si">true</a:RecordTracked>'
http://saop.si:DisplayMember = '<a:DisplayMember xmlns:a="http://saop.si">true</a:DisplayMember>'
```

as you can see, the custom properties (RecordTracked, DisplayName) are listed as well.

I have created 2 functions in within public class CodeStringGenerator to retrieve any custom property. Call it like this :

```
CodeStringGenerator.GetCustomPropertyAsBoolean(entity, "RecordTracked");


private bool GetCustomPropertyAsBoolean(GlobalItem item, string propertyName)
{
    var _value = GetCustomProperty(item, propertyName);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_value ))
    { return false; }

    return _value.Equals("true", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);        
}

private string GetCustomProperty(GlobalItem item, string propertyName)
{
    var _found = item.MetadataProperties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.StartsWith("http://") && 
                                                             p.Name.EndsWith(propertyName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase ));
    if (_found == null)
    { return string.Empty; }

    var _value = _found.Value as System.Xml.Linq.XElement;
    if (_value == null)
    { return string.Empty; }

    return _value.Value;
}
```